# Install packages in cache automatically

Tags: installation, cache

I have restored all my packages to cache using aptoncd. Now I want to reinstall the packages without having to choose each package. Is there any way?

Comment: Just run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: You just have to install aptoncd again, launch it and select the "Restore" tab, then "Restore .iso image".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I often use this technique. Open terminal type

```
sudo dpkg -i
```

Open Folder Where all .deb packages are located in another window in any media usb or CD, DVD. Select packages that you want to install. Now simply drag that packages to terminal. Come back to terminal  Press Enter. it will ask you password. Give it and packages are going to install.